# Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, restore

While restoring SharePoint 2010 site collection backup on dev server, I am getting below error, where my dev server has latest patches updates with SP2 and later.

> Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the
>   current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with
>   version '4.0.146.0' or later.

As you can see on below attached screenshot that web application on dev server has latest sharepoint foundation version

[image: As you can see in attached screenshot that web application on dev server has latest sharepoint foundation version]

Comment: The backup needs to be on the same version as the environment to restore to.

Comment: Hi @Chistoffer than you for quick reply, but my dev server has higher version than prod server as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As content DB source and destination Site Collection backup are of different SQL Sever version, so I have to restore DB backup and restore on DB for Dev machine and then attach that DB with my Dev sharepoint site as mentioned here [SharePoint restore fails because of newer version](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/sharepoint-restore-fails-because-of-newer-version)

Answer (score 0):

First, check the patch level of your source and destination environment. Make sure your destination environment is not at a lower version than the source. If so, you may need to patch your environment as same as your source.

Steps to Check Database Schema Versions:

Central Administration application > Management > Manage content databases. Select the database where you want to restore. Click on the DB name under “Database Versioning and Upgrade”.

For more information refer the below link,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30500.sharepoint-troubleshooting-your-backup-is-from-a-different-version-error-while-restoring-the-site.aspx

Comment: Hi Karthik, as you can see my dev server version has higher version than source environment. This is strange. I am able to restore site collection backup for other but facing above mention error for  this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SharePoint database status by doing the following:

Central Administration > Upgrade & Migration > Review database status->Below “Status” column, check the action required for each SharePoint Database.

Run the below cmdlet to upgrade all content database that still needs upgrade:

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | ?{$_.NeedsUpgrade -eq $true} | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

Comment: Thank you Lisa for quick reply, already tried Upgrade-SPContentDatabase command and got below message that DB is already upgraded

WARNING: Database [SPContentDatabase
Name=WSS_Content_SharePoint_SPDev2010_8282] does not need to be upgraded.

In Central Admin Content DB is also showing that it's upgraded for destination site collection.

Comment: Hi Lisa if content DB source and destination Site Collection backup are of different SQL Sever version, then it can be an issue in restore as mentioned here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/sharepoint-restore-fails-because-of-newer-version